# FirebaseException: [ DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH: Non-development mode Verification Proof given in development mode request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error

```
 error D/error here: onerrror: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An 
 internal error has occurred. [ DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH:Non-development 
 mode 
 Verification Proof given in development mode request. ]
```

On phone verification

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
       .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  ..... add user to database ...
                  }
              else {
                   Log.d("error here",task.getException());
                    }
                }
           }
}
```

I am new to this stuff and trying to learn things. I tried searching for this here but couldn't find anything useful. I tried changing the SHA1 keys and replaced the JSON file still its not working

Comment: Are you using whitelisted phone numbers by any chance? If so, was the user you are trying to sign in with created with a whitelisted phone number via the admin sdk?

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works fine now.i was using the same number to sign in the user  so when i tried using other number it worked i forgot to close the question. thank you for the reply

Answer (score 3):

This is just because maybe you added your number on firebase console ->

**Auth ->** **sign-in method -> phone number for testing** field

to solve this issue ... simply remove that number from testing field

it works for me..